# How to extract specific text not all text using iText?

Tags: android, pdf, itext, text-extraction

i am trying to extract word "Needless" ( [pdf link](http://www3.delta.edu/cmurbano/bio199/aids_sexuality/babyx.pdf) )

but getting whole text when i am extracting it so what should i do?

here is the way i am doing.

```
    String strfile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pk.pdf";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    PdfReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new PdfReader(strfile);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        try {
            //  System.out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i));
                data = sb.append(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i));
                System.out.println(data + "\n" + "PDF VERSION: " + reader.getPdfVersion()+ "\n" + "File Length: " + reader.getFileLength()+"\n"+"Info: "+reader.getInfo()+"\n"+"Require to Decrypt: " + reader.isEncrypted() + "\n" + "EOF: " + reader.getEofPos() + "\n" + reader.getLastXref());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

return data;
```

and this is taking too much time on device. so i don't want whole text?
is this possible?

Comment: Well, if you don't know where the text is you search, you have to go through all the pages and check whether they contain the text in question. Of course you do not need to *keep* all the text of all the pages (as you do in the `StringBuilder sb`: You can inspect the returned data from `PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage` first and only keep it if it contains interesting text.

Comment: is there way to only get the required character not the whole text? @mkl

Comment: You can create a custom `TextExtractionStrategy` which only returns desired text parts. There is a `PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage` overload which accepts an explicit `TextExtractionStrategy` parameter while your code uses the default `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`. Your `TextExtractionStrategy` replacement can throw away text chunks as soon as it is sure it cannot use them.